# To get Mail Id in controller

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

In my application am sending an mail[contains both TO and CC] through java. In that mail i have a link, while clicking the link it will redirected to controller.My question is there any way to get the mail id in controller. Because i need the find the difference between TO mail is and CC's.

Comment: I want to know from which mail id the link has been clicked

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your problem but if you're creating the links to put in your email message body can't you create different links for the different purposes?  Or do you want to send the same message to everyone and then determine whether the person who clicked on the link was someone in the To list vs. the Cc list?  You can't do that.  You would need to send two different messages with different links.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of JavaMail API‘s language, it provides three corresponding classes: Store, Folder and Message.
-          A Store object can be obtained from the current session by invoking the method getStore(String protocol) of Session class. Connecting to the Store by calling its method connect(String user, String pass), disconnecting by calling its close() method.

- A Folder object can be obtained from the store by invoking the getFolder(String folderName) method. For a regular mail box, the folder name must be “inbox” (case-insensitive). The most important methods of the Folder class are:

*open(int mode)*: Opens the folder either in READ_ONLY mode or READ_WRITE mode.

*getMessages():* Retrieves an array of Message objects which are marked un-read in the folder. A Message object may be a lightweight reference, and its detailed content will be filled up on demand.

*close(boolean expunge)*: Closes the folder, and permanently remove all messages which are marked delete, if expunge is true.

- A Message object represents an e-mail message. To get detailed attributes of a message, the following methods can be called on the Message object:

*Address[] getFrom()*: returns a list of senders in From attribute of the message.

*Address[] getRecipients(**Message.RecipientType type**)*: gets recipient addresses of the message, **type can be either TO or CC**.

*String getSubject()*: gets subject of the message.

*Date getSentDate()*: gets date and time when the message was sent.

*Object getContent()*: gets content of the message.